# Could not find artifact org.apache.pulsar:pulsar-broker:pom:2.12.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots)

Tags: maven, apache-pulsar

While following the instructions to setup IntelliJ for pulsar development I got the below error

```
Could not find artifact org.apache.pulsar:pulsar-broker:pom:2.12.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots)
```

Digging deeper into the snapshots, I don't see pulsar-broker at 2.12.0 either: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pulsar/pulsar-broker/

Is there some configuration step missing?

## Attempted Fix [RESOLVED]

*accepted answers steps and fix an issue with SDKMAN to have mvn call Java 17*

I tried the command `mvn -Pcore-modules,-main clean install -DskipTests -Dspotbugs.skip=true` and got the new error below.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project buildtools: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/brandon.hoffman/Projects/pulsar/buildtools/src/main/java/org/apache/pulsar/tests/RetryAnalyzer.java:[30,18] cannot access org.testng.ITestResult
[ERROR]   bad class file: /Users/brandon.hoffman/.m2/repository/org/testng/testng/7.7.0/testng-7.7.0.jar(org/testng/ITestResult.class)
[ERROR]     class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
[ERROR]     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this on the command line will fix that problem:

```
mvn -Pcore-modules,-main clean install -DskipTests -Dspotbugs.skip=true
```

You must use Java 17 for compiling the master branch version of Pulsar ([requirements](https://github.com/apache/pulsar#requirements)).

It's possible that there has been some change in the maven build after the instructions were originally written.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It's good to know the command line as well. Unfortunately, I'm getting a different error which I'll post in my question above.

Comment: Actually it looks like as you suggested from the command line I'm not using Java 17 though it is set in IntelliJ. I'm guessing this command will work.

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like the project is currently using the repository.apache.org for nightly snapshots. You should ask your question on the dev@pulsar.apache.org mailing list.

Also we have not yet cut the 2.12 branch. The VOTE for the first release of 2.11.0 just passed the PMC.

(FYI I am an Apache Pulsar PMC Member)